# World of Warcraft registration account using VB.NET with SRP6

Tags: vb.net, world-of-warcraft

Hello i'm having trouble with creating account from vb.net application to database.
I have make the stuff, it add in database the record, but when i try login ingame not recognize the password.
So it means that encryption is wrong somewhere. As i know storing in db is like Upper User + Upper Password. Maybe someone can help me to fix it.

```
Public Sub RegisterUser()
        Dim conStr = "Server=" + Data.Settings.MySQLServerHost + ";Uid=" + Data.Settings.MySQLServerUser + ";Database=" + Data.Settings.AuthDatabase + ";Port=" + Data.Settings.MySQLServerPort + ";Pwd=" + Data.Settings.MySQLServerPassword + ";"
        Dim salt(31) As Byte
        Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
            rng.GetBytes(salt)
        End Using
        ' calculate verifier using this salt
        Dim verifier As Byte() = SRP6.CalculateSRP6Verifier(TextAccountCreateName.Text, TextAccountPasswordCreate.Text, salt)
        ' done - this is what you put in the account table!
        Dim newSalt As Byte() = salt
        Dim newVerifier As Byte() = verifier
        'Dim result As Integer = $mysqli_auth->query("INSERT INTO account (username, email, salt, verifier) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$newSalt', '$newVerifier')")
        Try
            Using conn As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    Select Case Data.Settings.SelectedCore
                        Case Cores.AzerothCore
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO account (username, email, salt, verifier) VALUES (@user,@ema,@pass,@verif)"
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextAccountCreateName.Text)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ema", TextAccountEmailCreate.Text)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@verif", newVerifier)
                            If Data.Settings.EnableDBEncrypt And Data.Settings.DatabaseEncryption >= 1 Then
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", newSalt)
                            Else
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextAccountPasswordCreate.Text)
                            End If
                        Case Else
                            Exit Sub
                    End Select
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And here is my class

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Numerics
Public Class SRP6
    Public Shared Function CalculateSRP6Verifier(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal salt As Byte()) As Byte()
        ' algorithm constants
        Dim g As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("7")
        Dim N As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        ' calculate first hash
        Dim h1 As Byte() = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username.ToUpper() & ":" & password.ToUpper()))
        ' calculate second hash
        Dim h2 As Byte() = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(salt.Concat(h1).ToArray())
        ' convert to integer (little-endian)
        Dim h2Int As New BigInteger(h2.Reverse().ToArray())
        ' g^h2 mod N
        Dim verifier As BigInteger = BigInteger.ModPow(g, h2Int, N)
        ' convert back to a byte array (little-endian)
        Dim verifierBytes As Byte() = verifier.ToByteArray().Reverse().ToArray()
        ' pad to 32 bytes, remember that zeros go on the end in little-endian!
        Array.Resize(verifierBytes, 32)
        ' done!
        Return verifierBytes
    End Function
End Class
```

It stores in database the record, but when try login ingame it shows wrong information for password.

Comment: How is World of Warcraft related to the code you’re showing here? It’s not at all clear what the actual problem is - see [ask]

Comment: problem is code that stores info. Issue is encryption somewhere i make it wrong.